# Multiple array items appending

Tags: arrays, r, append

This is the reproducible code:

```
a <- rep(1, 20)
a[c(1, 12, 15)] <- 0
b <- which(a == 0)
set.seed(123)
d <- round(runif(17) * 100)
```

I would like to append `0`s to `d` to get the following result:

```
[1]  0 29 79 41 88 94  5 53 89 55 46  0 96 45  0 68 57 10 90 25
```

that is equal to `d` after appending `0`s to each element which has index equal to `b - 1`.

I've seen `append()` accepts just one single "after" value, not more than one.

How could I do?

Please, keep in mind I cannot change the length of `d` because it is supposed it's the ouput of a quite long function, not a simple random sequence like in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use negative subscripting to assign the non-zero elements to a new vector.

```
D <- numeric(length(c(b,d)))
D[-b] <- d
D
# [1]  0 29 79 41 88 94  5 53 89 55 46  0 96 45  0 68 57 10 90 25
```